# Update columns of database from csv file. Csv file could contain variable number of columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

Need your help. I have to get csv file from user and update database columns according to that file.
For Example:
File has following fields:



Name | Description | Date

Another file has:
Name  | Price 
Please Guide me how i could do this in c# using sql 2008.

[image]

From checkboxes user can select columns which he wants to update.

```
else if (count == 4 && dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1 == 4)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value);
                    ItemsC.UpdateDatacolumns(id, columnsList[1], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), columnsList[2], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), columnsList[3], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

                }
            }
          else if (count == 5 && dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1 == 5)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value);
                    ItemsC.UpdateDatacolumns(id, columnsList[1], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), columnsList[2], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), columnsList[3], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), columnsList[4], dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

                }
            }
```

In Backend Just Override Update Method:

```
    public static bool UpdateDatacolumns(int id, string column, string value, string column2, string value2)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = database.getConnection();
        string query = "update destinationItemTable set " + column + "= @value ," + column2+" =@value2 where Id=@id";
        try
        {
            var p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
            var p2 = new SqlParameter("@value", value);
            var p3 = new SqlParameter("@value2", value2);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandText = query, CommandType = CommandType.Text };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            bool result = (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
            cmd.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code about what you already tried.

Comment: Given the two files, what would the resulting table look like?

Comment: Do you have a table available in database? If so provide the schema of the table

Comment: Added Code. Please Check it.

Comment: I'm not clear what part(s) you're having issues with...  can you read the CSV file okay?  Are you able to select the columns successfully?  Is the update to the database working?  Can you narrow down the problem areas?  Without seeing the entire program, it's hard to assess where the problem is.  Don't post the entire thing (unless it's short), just help me understand what the issue is.

Comment: Its all working fine. But I want to do it in effective way as I have to define update methods as per number of columns. Is there any way to update dynamically.